# Output csv instead of snappy.parquet

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running the below:

```
  for x in days:
       for i in numbers:
           mega_query = spark.sql("select *  " \
                        "from db.table " \
                        "where date ={} " \
                        "and number = {} ".format(x, 1))

     
 
  mega_query.write.mode('append').options(header='true').save("/path/results2.csv")
```

I want to have one csv file at the end but instead of that I have many `snappy.parquet` files. How can I create only one csv with the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `.format("csv")` into your `.write` command. Otherwise it will use default Parquet format.

If you want to have one file, then you can add `.coalesce(1)` before `.write`, but this may not be the most optimal solution from performance standpoint

Answer (score 1):

daria][1](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria/) API, to create a single csv file with a specific filename.

```
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.DariaWriters

DariaWriters.writeSingleFile(
    df = df,
    format = "csv",
    sc = spark.sparkContext,
    tmpFolder = sys.env("HOME") + "/Documents/better/tmp",
    filename = sys.env("HOME") + "/Documents/better/mydata.csv"
)
```

You can find more details in the following tutorial.

https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/output-one-file-csv-parquet/

Comment: is it a pythonic code? I mean, how to import this package?

Comment: You need to add spark-daria.jar file to the classpath.

https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria/